# UCMA 3.0 - Recording an incoming call

Tags: ucma

I am new to UCMA and I am learning as I go through examples. I am trying to build 2 Lync clients A and B with the scenario as follows,

1. A calls B
2. B answers
3. A plays audio
4. B records it using Recorder.

I am stuck at trying to record the call at B. For B its an incoming call. I need to attach the audiovideoflow to the recorder, but I am not sure on how to do it. I will appreciate any help. 
Apologies on the unformatted code, I am not sure how to format it properly, I tried.

Thanks.
Kris

## Client B Code:

1. Accepts an incoming call
2. Records the media received in the incoming call. ***This is the part I have trouble

   using System;
   using System.Threading;
   using Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration;
   using Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.AudioVideo;
   using Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling;
   using Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Lync;

   namespace Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.LyncUAS
   {
       public class LyncUAS
       {
           #region Locals
           private LyncUASConfigurationHelper _helper;
           private UserEndpoint _userEndpoint;
           private AudioVideoCall _audioVideoCall;
           private AudioVideoFlow _audioVideoFlow;
           private Conversation _incomingConversation;

   ```
       //Wait handles are only present to keep things synchronous and easy to read.
       private AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
       private EventHandler<AudioVideoFlowConfigurationRequestedEventArgs> _audioVideoFlowConfigurationRequestedEventHandler;
       private EventHandler<MediaFlowStateChangedEventArgs> _audioVideoFlowStateChangedEventHandler;
       private AutoResetEvent _waitForAudioVideoCallEstablishCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
       private AutoResetEvent _waitForAudioVideoFlowStateChangedToActiveCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
       private AutoResetEvent _waitForPrepareSourceCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);

       #endregion

       #region Methods
       /// <summary>
       /// Instantiate and run the DeclineIncomingCall quickstart.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="args">unused</param>
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           LyncUAS lyncUAS = new LyncUAS();
           lyncUAS.Run();
       }

       private void Run()
       {
          string filename = "received.wma";

           _helper = new LyncUASConfigurationHelper();

           // Create a user endpoint, using the network credential object 
           // defined above.
           _userEndpoint = _helper.CreateEstablishedUserEndpoint("Lync UAS" /*endpointFriendlyName*/);
           _userEndpoint.RegisterForIncomingCall<AudioVideoCall>(On_AudioVideoCall_Received);
           Console.WriteLine("Waiting for incoming call...");
           _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
           Console.WriteLine("came after call is connected");
           //start recording for audio.

           Recorder recorder = new Recorder();            

           recorder.StateChanged += new EventHandler<RecorderStateChangedEventArgs>(recorder_StateChanged);
           recorder.VoiceActivityChanged += new EventHandler<VoiceActivityChangedEventArgs>(recorder_VoiceActivityChanged);
   ```

   //**********This is the issue, currently _audioVideoFlow is null, it is not attached to the flow
     //So this will fail, how to attach _audioVideoFlow to an incoming call ?? HELP !!!

   ```
          // recorder.AttachFlow(_audioVideoFlow);  ------------> HELP!


           WmaFileSink sink = new WmaFileSink(filename);
           recorder.SetSink(sink);
           recorder.Start();
           Console.WriteLine("Started Recording ...");
           _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
           recorder.Stop();
           Console.WriteLine("Stopped Recording ...");
           recorder.DetachFlow();
           Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
           Thread.Sleep(2000); 
       }


       private void audioVideoFlow_StateChanged(object sender, MediaFlowStateChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Flow state changed from " + e.PreviousState + " to " + e.State);

           //When flow is active, media operations can begin
           if (e.State == MediaFlowState.Active)
           {
               // Flow-related media operations normally begin here.
               _waitForAudioVideoFlowStateChangedToActiveCompleted.Set();
           }

           // call sample event handler
           if (_audioVideoFlowStateChangedEventHandler != null)
           {
               _audioVideoFlowStateChangedEventHandler(sender, e);
           }
       }


       void recorder_VoiceActivityChanged(object sender, VoiceActivityChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Recorder detected " + (e.IsVoice ? "voice" : "silence") + " at " + e.TimeStamp);
       }

       void recorder_StateChanged(object sender, RecorderStateChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Recorder state changed from " + e.PreviousState + " to " + e.State);
       }

       void On_AudioVideoCall_Received(object sender, CallReceivedEventArgs<AudioVideoCall> e)
       {
           //Type checking was done by the platform; no risk of this being any 
           // type other than the type expected.
           _audioVideoCall = e.Call;

           // Call: StateChanged: Only hooked up for logging, to show the call 
           // state transitions.
           _audioVideoCall.StateChanged += new
               EventHandler<CallStateChangedEventArgs>(_audioVideoCall_StateChanged);
           _incomingConversation = new Conversation(_userEndpoint);

           Console.WriteLine("Call Received! From: " + e.RemoteParticipant.Uri + " Toast is: " +e.ToastMessage.Message);
           _audioVideoCall.BeginAccept(
                ar =>
                {
                    try { 
                        _audioVideoCall.EndAccept(ar);
                        Console.WriteLine("Call must be connected at this point. "+_audioVideoCall.State);

                        _autoResetEvent.Set();
                         } catch (RealTimeException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }
                }, null);

       }

       //Just to record the state transitions in the console.
       void _audioVideoCall_StateChanged(object sender, CallStateChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Call has changed state. The previous call state was: " + e.PreviousState +
               " and the current state is: " + e.State);
           if (e.State == CallState.Terminated)
           {               
               Console.WriteLine("Shutting down");
               _autoResetEvent.Set();
               _helper.ShutdownPlatform();
           }
       }
       #endregion
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: +1 On this. I have kinda same issue. Having a incoming AVCall, where my Flow object is null, which means I cannot retrieve it back from hold etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out what's not quite right here.

#### Your Code

```
    // Create a user endpoint, using the network credential object 
    // defined above.
    _userEndpoint = _helper.CreateEstablishedUserEndpoint("Lync UAS" /*endpointFriendlyName*/);
    _userEndpoint.RegisterForIncomingCall<AudioVideoCall>(On_AudioVideoCall_Received);
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for incoming call...");
    _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("came after call is connected");
    //start recording for audio.

    Recorder recorder = new Recorder();            

    recorder.StateChanged += new EventHandler<RecorderStateChangedEventArgs>(recorder_StateChanged);
    recorder.VoiceActivityChanged += new EventHandler<VoiceActivityChangedEventArgs>(recorder_VoiceActivityChanged);         

     //**********This is the issue, currently _audioVideoFlow is null, it is not attached to the flow //So this will fail, how to attach _audioVideoFlow to an incoming call ?? HELP !!!
     // recorder.AttachFlow(_audioVideoFlow);  ------------> HELP!
```

Looking good so far. I'm assuming you're establishing and such in your `CreateEstablishedUserEndpoint` method, but I'm not seeing where you're getting the value for _audioVideoFlow.

I'm guessing you might be doing it elsewhere, but on the off chance that's actually where you're running into problems, here's that bit:

#### Simplest pattern to get AVFlow

```
    public static void RegisterForIncomingCall(LocalEndpoint localEndpoint)
    {
        localEndpoint.RegisterForIncomingCall
                          <AudioVideoCall>(IncomingCallDelegate);
    }

    private static void IncomingCallDelegate(object sender, CallReceivedEventArgs<AudioVideoCall> e)
    {
        e.Call.AudioVideoFlowConfigurationRequested += IncomingCallOnAudioVideoFlowConfigurationRequested;
    }

    private static void IncomingCallOnAudioVideoFlowConfigurationRequested(object sender, AudioVideoFlowConfigurationRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        AudioVideoFlow audioVideoFlow = e.Flow; // <--- There's your flow, gentleman.
    }
```

Now, instead of registering for your incoming call, just call `RegisterForIncomingCall(_userEndpoint);`.

Your AVFlow will be hanging off e.Flow above, you could then pass that into your recorder: `recorder.AttachFlow(e.Flow)` or simply assign the flow to a field in your class and `autoResetEvent.WaitOne();` and set that up where you're setting that up now.

Obviously this is a pretty naive implementation.  A lot can go wrong in those few lines of code (exception handling/static event handler memory leak comes immediately to mind); don't forget to wire up events related to status changes on the conversation/call and endpoints, as well as any of the recovery related items.